# Async API design client

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

Lets say I create an async REST API in Spring MVC with Java 8's Completeable.

How is this called in the client? If its non blocking, does the endpoint return something before processing? Ie

```
@RequestMapping("/")  //GET method
public CompletableFuture<String> meth(){
   thread.sleep(10000);  
   String result = "lol";
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
}
```

How does this exactly work? (This code above is just a randomly made code I just thought of).

When I send a GET request from say google chrome @ `localhost:3000/` then what happens? I'm a newbie to async APIs, would like some help.

Answer (score 3):

No, the client doesn't know it's asynchronous. It'll have to wait for the result normally. It's just the server side that benefits from freeing up a worker thread to handle other requests.

Comment: So what's the point of using CompleteableFuture, why not just use a new thread? So this doesnt improve API response times at all then?

Comment: Well you would use another thread. That's the one that completes the `CompletableFuture` and enables the result to be sent.

Comment: so what does it mean when people say Async improves API response time. How so exactly?

Comment: People say a lot of things.

Comment: So async doesnt improve api response time?

Comment: Depends on your API. It frees up threads to handle requests for possible shorter operations to be served. There's no sense in making all the endpoints asynchronous.

Comment: Because not all are long running operations.

Answer (score 2):

In this version it's pointless, because `CompletableFuture.completedFuture()` creates a completed Future immediately.

However in a more complex piece of code, you might return a `Future` that is not yet complete. Spring will not send the response body until some other thread calls `complete()` on this `Future`.

Why not just use a new thread? Well, you could - but in some situations it might be more efficient not to. For example you might put a task into an `Executor` to be handled by a small pool of threads.

Or you might fire off a JMS message asking for the request to be handled by a completely separate machine. A different part of your program will respond to incoming JMS messages, find the corresponding `Future` and complete it. There is no need for a thread dedicated to this HTTP request to be alive while the work is being done on another system.

Very simple example:

```
 @RequestMapping("/employeenames/{id}") 
 public CompletableFuture<String> getName(@PathVariable String id){
     CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

     database.asyncSelect(
         name -> future.complete(name),
         "select name from employees where id = ?",
         id
     );

     return future;
  }
```

I've invented a plausible-ish API for an asynchronous database client here: `asyncSelect(Consumer<String> callback, String preparedstatement, String... parameters)`. The point is that it fires off the query, then does not block the tread waiting for the DB to respond. Instead it leaves a *callback* (`name -> future.complete(name)`) for the DB client to invoke when it can.

This is not about improving API response times -- we do not send an HTTP response until we have a payload to provide. This is about using the resources on the server more efficiently, so that *while we're waiting for the database to respond* it can do other things.

---

There is a related, but different concept, of asynch REST, in which the server responds with `202 Accepted` and a header like `Location: /queue/12345`, allowing the client to poll for the result. But this isn't what the code you asked about does.

Comment: Can you give an example of returning an incomplete Future? How does all this improve API response times is my main question.

Answer (score 0):

`CompletableFuture`  was introduced by Java to make handling complex asynchronous programming. It lets the programmer combine and cascade async calls, and offers the static utility methods `runAsync` and supplyAsync to abstract away the manual creation of threads.

These methods dispatch tasks to Java’s common thread pool by default or a custom thread pool if provided as an optional argument.

If a CompletableFuture is returned by an endpoint method and #complete is never called, the request will hang until it times out.